# How to read convert String to JSON in Boost in Android

Tags: android, json, react-native, boost, java-native-interface

I have been trying to read JSON data from a JSON string, but my app keeps crashing immediately after it starts. No errors are displayed.

The JSON string is passed from the Javascript code in React Native :

```
let myJSONString = JSON.stringify({foo: "bar"});
```

The CMakeLists.txt file that sets up boost :

```
set(my_boost_dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/ndk_25_boost_1.79.0)

set(MY_BOOST_LIBS_DIR ${my_boost_dir}/libs)
set(MY_BOOST_INC_DIR ${my_boost_dir}/include)


#-----------------------------------------
add_library (libboost_container SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties( libboost_container PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${MY_BOOST_LIBS_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libboost_container.so
        )
#-----------------------------------------


#-----------------------------------------
add_library (libboost_json SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties( libboost_json PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${MY_BOOST_LIBS_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libboost_json.so
        )
#-----------------------------------------


#-----------------------------------------
add_library (libboost_system SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties( libboost_system PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${MY_BOOST_LIBS_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libboost_system.so
        )
#-----------------------------------------
add_library( libboost_chrono SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(libboost_chrono PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${MY_BOOST_LIBS_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libboost_chrono.so
        )
#-----------------------------------------

include_directories( ${MY_BOOST_INC_DIR}
        )
```

This is how I try reading the JSON string :

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_ca_com_1gen_1lib_1pers_c_1libs_1core_MyStringToJSON_myStringToJSON(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                               jobject instance,
                                                                               jstring myJSONStringEntity_)
{
    const char *myJSONStringEntity = env->GetStringUTFChars(myJSONStringEntity_, 0);

    // Short alias for this namespace
    namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

    // Create a root
    pt::ptree root;

    // Load the json file in this ptree
    pt::read_json(myJSONStringEntity, root);

    // Read values
    std::string returnVal = root.get<std::string>("foo", 0);

    return returnVal;
}
```

Where am I doing it wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing Boost JSON (a JSON library) and Boost Property (a Property Tree Library). Only use the first!

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf03d13db520f811)**

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for COLIRU (header-only)
#include <iostream>

#define JNIEXPORT
#define JNICALL
using jstring = std::string;
struct jobject { };
struct JNIEnv { char const* GetStringUTFChars(jstring const& s, int) { return s.data(); } };

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_ca_com_1gen_1lib_1pers_c_1libs_1core_MyStringToJSON_myStringToJSON(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                               jobject /*instance*/,
                                                                               jstring myJSONStringEntity_)
{
    const char *myJSONStringEntity = env->GetStringUTFChars(myJSONStringEntity_, 0);

    // Short alias for this namespace
    namespace bj = boost::json;

    // Create a root
    bj::value root = bj::parse(myJSONStringEntity);

    // Read values
    std::string returnVal{root.at("foo").as_string()};

    return returnVal;
}

int main() {
    auto f = Java_com_ca_com_1gen_1lib_1pers_c_1libs_1core_MyStringToJSON_myStringToJSON;

    std::cout << "Example: " << f(nullptr, {}, R"({"foo":"bar", "qux": [1,2,3]})") << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Example: bar
```

Comment: Hi there @sehe. Thank you for the response. I've tried it your way, but it still fails on Android. I'm still not sure if I'm doing it right in the CMake.text file. Could you please advise. How should the set-up be on Android (React Native)? Thank you again.

Comment: You should try to be more specific ("It fails" can be many things)

Comment: The app closes as soon as it opens. Removing the `#include <boost/json.hpp>`  imports solves the problem and the app runs just fine. However, other libraries such as `#include <boost/chrono.hpp>` work just fine

Comment: Including any of the `boost/json***` headers cause the app to crash as soon as it launches with no error warnings

Comment: Are you saying that happens with https://godbolt.org/z/o1Yzzs1db? Otherwise, the "obvious" culprit is your code